# Tailwind Rebuild never stops

Tags: javascript, flask, tailwind-css

My Flask app uses Tailwind for the css. The website was working perfectly before but recently I've started encountering issues with tailwind. I have run a tailwind build script for my app and normally the script would update css if it detects changes in any of the target files.

However, when I run the script now, recently the tailwind just says 'Rebuilding...' without the 'Done' message. so the rebuild never stops.

```
(venv) danish@Danishs-MacBook-Air portfolio-website % npm run tailwind

> portfolio-website@1.0.0 tailwind
> npx tailwindcss -i ./static/src/input.css -o ./static/css/main.css --watch


Rebuilding...
```

How do I fix this issue?

Edit: This problem started occurring around the time I started another flask project that uses tailwind. Tailwind on the other app works exactly as intended, even though the installation process was exactly the same and the file structure is the same. Could this have caused it?

@Erik-Jan

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./static/src/input.css -o ./static/css/main.css --minify"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling dependencies by deleting `node_modules`?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You're running the `--watch` so i guess it's still watching for changes.

As it seems you're running step 4 of: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

When you want to build it for production, see: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production

Comment: I tried it but it's still showing ```Rebuilding...``` like before

Comment: What is in your package.json file?

Comment: This is in my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./static/src/input.css -o ./static/css/main.css --minify"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```